# How do I ensure that all Threads are stopped before main Thread is stopped?

Tags: java, multithreading

This is my program in which a thread is started under the main method

```
public class ThreadTest {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
        Thread t1 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    System.out.println("Hi");
                }
            }
        };
        // t1.setDaemon(true);
        t1.start();

    }
}
```

How do I ensure that before the main thread is stopped all its child Threads are stopped?

I don't want to use the Daemon option. Is this possible?

Comment: You can enumerate all threads and check teyr states. But what problem you want to solve? What you will do if find out that some thread isn't stoped?

Comment: What are you going to do after the thread(s) have finished, i.e. why do you care?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main thread you can wait for the other Threads to be finished.

In a method executed by the main thread do (in your example the main method):

```
t1.join();
```

But remember that if `t1` will never finish the main thread will never finish. So you migth want to use
join with a timeout.

```
t1.join(10000);
```

Comment: child thread to join with main thread, this will wait till child thread completed before continue.

Comment: @PuWang yes it will. This is what the OP asked for. isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `t1.join()`, `join()` method makes main thread or any other thread, in with it was called, wait until this task will end and then continue it's work. In your case, your program Will never finish execution until call `System.exit(0);` or make `t1.join(1000); // wait only for one second`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add t1.join() add the end of your method:

```
t1.start();
t1.join();
```

The main thread will wait until t1 is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one child thread, suggest you to try the signal

Answer (score 0):

```
t1.join();
System.out.println(mainThread.getName());
System.out.println(t1.getName());
```

main thread will wait until execution of t1 finishes